# Mysterious! Beamer itemize has no bullets after adding a few packages

Tags: beamer, packages, itemize

this is my first time using `beamer`.

I copied a template from the sharelatex page on Beamer

Which works, and `\begin{itemize}` shows bullets

[image]

But after adding a few more packages that I need, all the bullets are gone!

[image]

What is going on and how can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm}     %Theorem Environment 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{upgreek}    
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 

    %Information to be included in the title page: \title{Sample title} \author{Anonymous} \institute{ShareLaTeX} \date{2014}

\begin{document}   
\frame{\titlepage}   
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Sample frame title} 
\begin{itemize}
\item  This is a text in first frame. 
\item This is a text in first frame.
\item This is a text in first frame. 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The mystery is `enumitem` ... it is not compatible with `beamer`

Comment: Wouldn't a detective start *removing* the packages they added one by one until they found the one that caused the problem? :)  This is what is called a Minimal Working Example, i.e. a document that contains *only* enough code to show the problem.  Making such an example can often identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Off-topic: `subfigure` is obsolete. It ought not be used. `amssymb` makes `amsfonts` unnecessary, I think. `graphicx` is loaded by Beamer anyway. I would start by not loading `amsthm`, `thmtools` and `upgreek` with Beamer. You don't want environments which are not configured for Beamer here, generally. Try Beamer's variants first. Those are overlay-specification aware. `mathtools` loads `amsmath`. Changes to fonts will not work the ways you see them work in other classes, so start by not changing the defaults used for text and maths. (Adding more symbols etc. should be OK.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`beamer` has own, sophisticated mechanism to deal with lists (itemize, enumerate, description) which is *not compatible* with `enumitem`. Remove this package from preamble and all will work again.

After some cleaning of your preamble the MWE (Minimal Working Example) is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}     %Theorem Environment
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
% \usepackage{graphicx} it is loaded by beamer
\usepackage{subfig}% if you really needed
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a text in first frame.
\item This is a text in first frame.
\item This is a text in first frame.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]