# Beamer itemize has no bullets

Tags: beamer, xetex, itemize

I don't use package "enumitem"
[Mysterious! Beamer itemize has no bullets after adding a few packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387420/mysterious-beamer-itemize-has-no-bullets-after-adding-a-few-packages)

overleaf is OK. so what's wrong with my setting?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{A}
\author{B}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Facts about }
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is text
        \item 测试
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome. I cannot reproduce your problem with TeX Live 2021. Both bullets do appear in my pdf file. Perhaps you want to upgrade your tex distribution to the latest version?

Comment: @modnar I will try. I use TeX Live 2020

Answer (score 3):

I tried your file and got the following pdf file:
[image]

Comment: I run this in cmd xelatex. no bullets

Comment: I did use xelatex to compile your file. The above is what the generated pdf looks like, in which the bullets do appear. That's why I suggested to upgrade your tex distribution to the latest version.